# mysql import sql file has error : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am trying to import data to mysql, but got this error:

> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

here is my command, I now am import table cdrdata data to another cdrdata table, db name ucl_db

> mysql -u root -p ucl_db

[image]

> here is cdrdata-oldsystem.sql

[image]

> here is the target ucl_db cdrdata table I am going to import in

[image]

is that because the id is same so I got this error??

Comment: The primary key, your 'ID' needs to be unique. If you are using autoincrement for the primary key leave the ID out of the insert statement

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**